# UItableview headerview with custom uiview?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiview

I am creating a custom uiview that contains an uilabel and an uiimage assigned to an uiimageview. I assign the custom uiview to the uitableview headerview but i only see the uilabel not the uiimage...please help this is my code...

```
UIView *containerView1 =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30)];

UILabel *headerLabel1 =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 4, 300, 20)];
    headerLabel1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    headerLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"- Latest update %@ -", now];
    headerLabel1.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    headerLabel1.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    headerLabel1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    headerLabel1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"line_seperator.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30, 30)];

    imageView.image = image;
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [containerView1 addSubview:headerLabel1];
   [containerView1 addSubview:imageView];
    [containerView1 addSubview:indicator2];

   walltable.tableHeaderView = containerView1;
```

Any help appreciated.

Forgot to say that this code executes after the uitableview loads.

Comment: Try self.tableView.tableHeadView = containerView1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it. The image was not right. The image was downloaded from the web as .gif . I opened it in photoshop and saved it as .png but it did not saved correctly. I created a new image in photoshop and copy the one i had in that new image. I saved it as .png and it worked.